# unlisting the directory names in batch script

Tags: windows, batch

I am using the following command to list all the files (with absolute path) other than the undesired folders.

Just a small problem , i don't want to list just directory name as listed in below first three entries.

```
C:\Listings\D1
C:\Listings\D2
C:\Listings\D3
```

How can i do that.
Thanks

```
dir /S /B * | findstr /v /i UD

C:\Listings>dir /S /B * | findstr /v /i UD
C:\Listings\D1
C:\Listings\D2
C:\Listings\D3
C:\Listings\D1\d1_file.txt.txt
C:\Listings\D2\d2_file.txt.txt
C:\Listings\D3\d3_file.txt.txt
```

Comment: I don't get this result. What is your Windows version?

Comment: windows  version 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/A-D` switch to the command:

```
dir /A-D /S /B * | findstr /v /i UD
```

This switch excludes directories (with directory attributes).

Comment: Thanks Wasif, that works

Answer (score 1):

And the **PowerShell** equivalent...
Verbose:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

With [aliases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-7):

```
gci -af -r -ea silent | select -exp FullName
```

The above starts outputting results immedidately, facilitating further pipeline processing.

The alternate construction:

```
( gci -af -r -ea silent ).FullName
```

...completes the recursive query before selecting the FullName property and returning results.

[Get-ChildItem/gci](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative:

```
where /r . *
```

Where only list files and with the fullpath:

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

  [√] **[Where /ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**

  [√] 
  **[Some options and examples](https://superuser.com/a/1578285/969781)**